# LaTeX3 conditional with grouping fails to compile

Tags: package-writing, expl3, latex3

I am trying to write a LaTeX3 conditional using `\prg_new_conditional:Nnn` from the `expl3` package. Since the code in the conditional needs to make assignments to some variables, I would like to use grouping in order to do those assgnments locally. However, the following MWE fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \foo: { p }
{
  \group_begin:
    % Do some stuff.
  \group_end:
  \prg_return_true:
}
\bool_if:nTF { \foo_p: } { true } { false }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The following errors show up several times:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\group_begin:
l.11 \bool_if:nTF { \foo_p: }
{ true } { false }
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\group_begin:
l.11 \bool_if:nTF { \foo_p: }
{ true } { false }
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

When I remove `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:`, then everything works as expected. So what is going on here? Why can't I use grouping within the definition of `\foo_p:`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A conditional allowing the predicate form must be fully expandable, but `\group_begin:` isn't. So, no grouping nor assignments.

Comment: Such statements appear from time to time in the LaTeX3 interface manual, but I never really understood them. Could you elaborate on this a bit further?

Comment: consider something simpler like a simple primitive count assignment. you can go `\def\z{123}\count0=\z` as `\z` _expands_ to 123, but you can not go `\def\z{{123}}\count0=\z` as then `\z` expands to `{123}` which isn't a legal number. Same here the `\group_begin:` stops the argument being interpreted as true or false.

Comment: If the code is not expandable, the correct would be `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn`… which explicitly bans the `p` branch. So, it's not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to work, a predicate such as `\foo_p:` that you'd like to use must expand to either `\prg_return_true:` or `\prg_return_false:`, leaving nothing else in the input stream after macro expansion.

In the code for the replacement text you are free to use any of the conditionals marked with a (filled) * in the `interface3` manual and, in their true or false parts, only functions marked in the same way.

With your definition, `\group_begin:` will remain unless hidden in code that's always skipped, but in that case it would be useless. No assignment can be performed in the code for a conditional that's supposed to have a predicate form, because assignments are not performed during macro expansion.

So, for example, it's impossible to have a predicate form for a conditional that's supposed to decide whether some tokens will end up with typeset text, say by doing `\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {<tokens>}` and then measuring the box.

Depending on what you want to do, there could be expandable ways.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer, egreg! So could you say that a group by design is never "empty", even though its contents leave nothing in the input stream?

What I am actually trying to achieve is to check whether a token list is composed of certain characters. My current approach is to assign an input parameter to a token list and performe some actions on this variable. All this would preferrably be done locally. Finally I can run a test on the token list variable to output `\prg_return_true:` or `\prg_return_false:`. Am I missing some obvious way how to turn this into expandable code?

Comment: @ranguwud No code containing assignments can be made fully expandable.

Comment: @egreg I know an edge case, but a piece of LuaTeX-only code could do the assignment at the Lua end and remain expandable.

Comment: @ranguwud Series of expandble loops, outer one over the input data, inner one over the allowed chars?

Comment: @JosephWright This sounds indeed like a promising approach, but how would I remember if I found a "forbidden" character without setting a bool or something similar? As far as I know, `\tl_break:` cannot be used to terminate *two* loops. At least not without using groups. :)

Comment: @ranguwud A separate question, really, and I think would need an example of what kind of input we are searching and for what.